# Colour space matching iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics, color-space, color-management, cgcolorspace

I have a purple color from a design that has a hex value of #ae359f.

I convert this hex into a UIColor, load it on the simulator and take a screenshot.

I open both the design and the screenshot in photoshop, and use the eyedropper and they both have the same hex value of #ae359f, however, they are visibly different colours.

Must be a colorspace issue - which I've read about a few times and still don't really get it. If its on the same device why the f can't #ae359f be the same everywhere! Who's fault is this.

So, the question is... how can i make UIColor look like AdobeRGB values - i can do it in interface builder I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color Management is not supported on iOS in this graphics stack. Quartz et al will treat your colors as sRGB.

You *could* introduce a conversion routine for AdobeRGB -> sRGB, but the easy way is to just provide colors in sRGB values.

---

There's a little disclaimer at the end of the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGColorSpace/index.html).

> **COLOR SPACES AND IOS**
>
> iOS does not support ColorSync, so all assets should be provided in the native device color space: sRGB.

More info in this Tech Note: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2313/_index.html

Comment: Cheers. I ended up just pasting my screenshot into photoshop, then pasting the colour swabs from the design into the same photoshop document - it threw up some colour profile warning.... i accepted. Then i just eyedropped them and put the hex's into iOS. It worked... albeit what seemed like a ridiculous convoluted process.

Comment: @bandejapaisa you're welcome. using Digital Color Meter, you can configure it to use sRGB and hex and use its eyedropper. saves a few steps.

Comment: Excellent. Didn't know I had this Digital Color Meter. Thanks for the tip.